# Paste html from textarea to Contenteditable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable, paste

I'm developing a RTE(rich text editor) using a wrapper div.

```
<div id="myeditor"></div>
//then
editorfunction(myeditor);
What the function does is add the following elements
<div id="myeditor">
    <div class="toolbar">buttons here</div>
    <div class="editorwrapper">
      <div class="editor-richtext">
         rich text etc
      </div>
      <textarea class="editor-source"><p>rich text etc</p></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can successfully grab the html from the .editor-richtext and put it inside the textarea, but when I edit the textarea, I don't seem to be able to paste that back into the rich-text.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**
Ok, it seems that

```
$("richtext").blur(function() {
   $("textarea").val($(this).html());
});
```

Works fine, but not the other way around (from textarea to richtext).

**Update 2**
It seems it is very unstable, it partially works but is acting strange :\
I'm not able to fully get content from textarea and paste as html into contenteditable. I will continue to do some research.

**Update 3**
I just updated update 1 and update 2 as I totally flipped textarea and richtext in my brain. Sorry!

**Update 4**
Ok, I pretty much got it solved now. I just have one slight problem, upon initialization, if I don't focus the contenteditable div and switch to the source view\textarea. the textarea is emptied, and when I then go back to RTE view\contenteditable div it is emptied. from the empty textarea\source.
I'm working on a work-around.

Comment: Here is the [entire project on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDYZp/25/)

Comment: Alright man, I think your original question was fully answered. You're just adding more requirements to it. Close this one, phrase your problem well and open a new one, right now it looks that you're not sure how it should work yourself.

Comment: Yep. I've since encountered more strange problems too, I'll open another one. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook the onBlur event of textarea to copy the text and paste it in editor-richtext

```
$("textarea.editor-source").blur(function(){
   $("div.editor-richtext").html($(this).val());
});
```

EDIT

For other way around, you can use the following code segment

```
$("textarea.editor-source").focus(function(){
   $(this).val($("div.editor-richtext").text());
});
```

Comment: What does the blur function do? does it fetch the html content? or is this a live event that goes continously? I'm gonnna try it now :P thanks.

Comment: It is fired when the focus shifts from the textarea.

Comment: Alright, it seems to work wonderfully from textarea TO contenteditable. But not the other way around.

    code?

Comment: But you said "I can successfully grab the html from the .editor-richtext and put it inside the textarea" do you need code for that as well?

Comment: Oh. yea, right. I had that working but it was messy, it brought lots of whitespace over to the textarea. I could probably strip that away though but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I see. thanks. But there's still the same problem I have where it grabs a whole bunch of whitespace. I'd like to remove that whitespace and possibly keep newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use jQuery and the following functionnalities?

```
$(".editor-source").keyup(function() {
    $(".editor-richtext").html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine. Selectors in your example are incorrect thought:

HTML:

```
  <div class="editor-richtext">
     original text
  </div>

  <textarea class="editor-source">modified text</textarea>
```

JS:

```
  $(".editor-source").blur(function() {
     $(".editor-richtext").html($(this).val());
  });​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDYZp/)

***UPD:***

```
$(".editor-richtext").click(function(){
    $(".editor-source").val($(this).html().trim());
});
```

​
[**new demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDYZp/2/) that puts content from `div` into `textarea` on click event.

Comment: Nice. It seems to work, although the blur doesn't work, neither does focus(). I guess I can transfer textarea content to richtext div when the user loses focus on the textarea? I'll try on jsfiddle. Here is the whole damn project in jsfiddle :P